# Saving IntelliJ Run Configurations in a custom location

Tags: intellij-idea

I'd like to save my run configurations in a custom location.

Is this possible or does everthing have to be stored in .idea/runConfigurations - I can't seem to find a Save As option?

I'm using version 12 EAP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you save it somewhere else, intellij won't pick it up and it would be redundant.

You could add the file to your source control system in its normal location.